# Why am I getting {"detail":[{"loc":["path","id"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]} if I made query with params?

Tags: python, fastapi, fastapi-crudrouter

This is the endpoint that is not working:

```py
@router.get(
    "/{question_id}",
    tags=["questions"],
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
    response_model=Question,
    dependencies=[Depends(get_db)],
)
def get_question(id: int = Path(..., gt=0)):
    return get_question_service(id)
```

This is what the server shows when I run the query from the interactive FastAPI docs:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:45806 - "GET /api/v1/questions/%7Bquestion_id%7D HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable
```

I don't know why it is sending `{question_id}` here instead of the number.

Also when I run a query from curl, this is what the server shows:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59104 - "GET /api/v1/questions/21 HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

It makes no sense since I'm sending the only required param: `(question_id)`

The other endpoint is working fine:

```py
@router.get(
    "/",
    tags=["questions"],
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
    response_model=List[Question],
    dependencies=[Depends(get_db)],
)
def get_questions():
    return get_questions_service()
```

Comment: generally try to change `@router.get("/{question_id}"` to `@router.get("/{id}"` that way you will 'tell' the endpoint to wait for id path parameter and in request add something `<endpoint>/5` also `def get_question(id: int = Path(..., gt = 0))` try with `def get_question(id: int)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the path parameter in the path string and the function argument. Rename the function argument to `question_id`

```py
@router.get(
    "/{question_id}",
    tags=["questions"],
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
    response_model=Question,
    dependencies=[Depends(get_db)],
)
def get_question(question_id: int = Path(..., gt=0)):
    return get_question_service(question_id)
```

or the path parameter to `id`:

```py
@router.get(
    "/{id}",
    tags=["questions"],
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
    response_model=Question,
    dependencies=[Depends(get_db)],
)
def get_question(id: int = Path(..., gt=0)):
    return get_question_service(id)
```

---

Btw, `...` in `Path` can be omitted.
`id: int = Path(gt=0)` is equivalent to `id: int = Path(gt=0)`